# How much heat can roofing underlayment take?

Tags: roofing

I need to trim some nails sticking out the bottom of the roof deck.  These are good-sized ring-shank nails that roofers couldn't hit the rafters with when they were putting down new plywood over old plank sheathing.  I need them flush.  The most effective way is to do this with a dremel.  However, the nails get hot from the friction.  Not hot enough to singe wood or paper but hot enough to blister skin.

There is synthetic roofing underlayment (should be [Tri-Flex](https://gcpat.com/en/solutions/products/tri-flex-synthetic-underlayment/tri-flex-xt-synthetic-underlayment)) directly over the heads of these nails.  Can the hot nails damage the underlayment?  How much heat can synthetic roofing underlayment take?

Comment: Perhaps you can find an area you can do a test on.

Answer (score 1):

I clipped a bit of the underlayment to experiment with.  Cutting a nail with a dremel cutoff wheel on medium speed does produce enough heat to melt the underlayment.  Cutting the nail on low speed with breaks, the underlayment seems alright.

This was a conservative experiment.  I didn't have a whole nail to play with so I used a clipping.  The cut was over the underlayment sample, not 1-1/4in away, but heat spreads quickly through the metal.

I've cut nails with an angle grinder before: the nails get red hot so that's not better.  I'm going with end nippers except where I need them really flush in which case I'm using a hacksaw blade.

Answer (score 0):

The triflex website you link says:

> Do not install under copper, Cor-Ten®, or zinc metal roofing in high  altitudes or in the desert southwest. These roofs can reach extremely high temperatures due to the low reflectivity, high absorption, and high conductivity of the metals.

So it looks like the stuff does not like it hot.

Probably you'll have to find a different method,

Experiment with an angle grinder with a 1mm thick cut-off wheel, they have bigger motors than Dremels and thus should cut faster than the Dremel. that should mean that less heat gets into the work.

Experiment with doing partial cuts and then resting to allow the nail to cool.

You might have to resort to hand tools like a single-ended hacksaw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an *end nipper* for roofing nails that miss the rafters ("shiners") because it is fast and easy; bonus for you is no heat involved:

[image]

Comment: I've been using end-nippers but that still leaves a stump that sticks out.  This is fine for most of them but not all.  Also, a few just glanced off the rafter so nippers can't reach the base.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking on trimming the nail shafts that missed the rafters ?  Ring shanks are used for sheeting, and decking , and if you think you could do any better work a layer in between or any contractor can I will gladly provide a 100 point bonus on this site for any one that thinks they can do better!!!

If any nail head below a underlayment would be a problem I would not want anything to do with that material as in the high desert 120 degree temps are normal   With +40 to 60 degree surface temps  or close to 200f in some areas , yes with degrees colder would still be a problem with your numbers so I question them.

If you are talking about membrane roofing the nails below the surface are not relevant, white membrane reflects heat and is the most common.

Rolled roofing will get really hot but takes a torch to seam the sections  still normally below surface temps of black colored roofing.

Possibly more information is needed but after spending decades with the above roof types and others , I have never seen the fasteners, nails or screws cause a problem with heat underneath a roofing material of any kind on the coast or high desert. Well yes even at my uncle Steve’s house in the Mohave desert.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: Well I have done many roofs ,from the 1930’s  on Victorians that were as old as -1880 , yes only 2 of these and as I answered I would provide 100+ fora honest answer , but only - from cowards, read , understand  what I said, and only the cowards cans down vote as they have no experience as I have sorry COWARDS! Keep it coming just found out how to track you and I don’t care of my count I only answer  not edit and wait for others to answers! If

Comment: I'm asking if trimming the nails from below with a grinder will heat them up enough to burn Tri-Flex underlayment.  You're telling me that nails sticking through the sheathing will not cause problems regardless of roofing type or climate.  Good to know but downvoted because it is not the answer to my question.

Comment: Maybe I was not sure because of the rant of missed nails.

Comment: There is one sentence that describes the nails and why they're there.  I won't lie, I'm not happy they're there, but I don't think that's a rant.